# Can't Connect to Elasticsearch (through Curl)

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I've recently installed Elasticsearch and everything was working well for the first few days, but somehow today it stopped working

When I start the service, it claims to be fine...

```
sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
* Starting Elasticsearch Server
...done.
```

But then I get
`curl -GET http://127.0.0.1:9200`
`curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`

Looking at the elasticsearch logs:

```
[WARN ][bootstrap                ] jvm uses the client vm, make sure to run `java` with the server vm for best performance by adding `-server` to the command line
```

Looks like there is a warning regarding the Java VM; could that be the problem? What else should I try/look at?

Comment: update your `$ java -version` and elasticsearch configuration changes if you made any. Your es log tells it's only a `warn`.

Comment: Is there anywhere I could see a log of what is happening under the hood? Could it be that ES is listening on a different IP/port?

Comment: might be. You can check which port is es listening on with `lsof` command.

Comment: Looking at the output of `lsof`, it seems elasticsearch was not running because its startup script contained an error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**1) Check what's the status of your port 9200,** with `lsof` command in linux.

In my case following is the result when `elasticsearch` is started.

```
prayag@prayag:~$ sudo lsof -i TCP | grep 9200 
chrome  2639 praayg   84u  IPv4 116310      0t0  TCP prayag.local:58989->10.0.4.70:9200 (ESTABLISHED)
chrome  2639 prayag   99u  IPv4 116313      0t0  TCP prayag.local:58990->10.0.4.70:9200 (ESTABLISHED)
java    7634 prayag  141u  IPv6 130960      0t0  TCP *:9200 (LISTEN)
```

`elasticsearch` is not a service to me, otherwise to find the **port** es is running; on I could have checked,

```
$ sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep elasticsearch
```

**2) check the elasticsearch endpoint**

```
$ curl -IGET http://localhost:9200
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 327
```

- `-IGET` is equivalent to `--head` that returns http response headers only.
- response `200` means elasticsearch endpoint is responding properly.

Comment: Hi, I am getting something else:
[root@root ~]# sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep elasticsearch
java    1375 elasticsearch  100u  IPv6  12397      0t0  TCP *:vrace (LISTEN)
java    1375 elasticsearch  108u  IPv6  12467      0t0  TCP *:wap-wsp (LISTEN)
Do you maybe know from where does this happen?

Comment: @Tomer had not seen that but if you check TCP/UDP ports lists, you see title [`WAP-WSP` is port 9200](http://www.tcp-udp-ports.com/port-9200.htm) while [`VRace` is port 9300](http://www.tcp-udp-ports.com/port-9300.htm). _(check the hyperlinks)_

Answer (score 10):

`curl -GET http://127.0.0.1:9200` is the wrong command.

Try `curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200`. It should return the short info about your running local node and status 200. If that doesn't work then something else must be wrong.

Comment: I tried curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200 and I'm still getting curl: (7) couldn't connect to host.

Comment: is your elasticsearch server running? I.e does `sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch status` report that it is running?

Comment: indeed, the server was not running. I'm using Upstart (on Ubuntu) to start up the server automatically and it was not being started. Thanks for the tip on how to check. In my case (Upstart), the command was `sudo initctl elasticsearch status`

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, I'd try the command:

curl -XGET http://localhost:9200

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to memory allocation and usage. In case you let it use unlimited memory it might crash when you least suspect. Here is a tutorial on Elasticseach 5 and Kibana in case anyone else runs into this issue. https://medium.com/@adnanxteam/how-to-install-elasticsearch-5-and-kibana-on-homestead-vagrant-60ea757ff8c7