# Client is not connected to any Elasticsearch nodes in Flink

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, apache-flink, elasticsearch-plugin, flink-streaming

I am using Flink 1.1.2 and have added ElesticSearch dependency in Maven as follows

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-elasticsearch2_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

My program contains the following code that is reading data from Kafka and inserting to Elastic search

```
public class ReadFromKafka {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // create execution environment
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");


        DataStream<JoinedStreamEvent> message = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<JoinedStreamEvent>("test",
                new JoinSchema(), properties));

        System.out.println("reading form kafka ");

        message.print();


        Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put("bulk.flush.max.actions", "1");   // flush inserts after every event
        config.put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch_amar"); // default cluster name

        List<InetSocketAddress> transports = new ArrayList<>();
// set default connection details
        transports.add(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));

       message.addSink(new ElasticsearchSink<>(config,transports,new ElasticInserter()));

        env.execute();


    } //main

    public static class ElasticInserter implements ElasticsearchSinkFunction<JoinedStreamEvent>{


        @Override
        public void process(JoinedStreamEvent record, RuntimeContext runtimeContext, RequestIndexer requestIndexer) {

            Map<String, Integer> json = new HashMap<>();

            json.put("Time", record.getPatient_id());
            json.put("heart Rate ", record.getHeartRate());
            json.put("resp rete", record.getRespirationRate());


            IndexRequest rqst = Requests.indexRequest()
                    .index("nyc-places")           // index name
                    .type("popular-locations")     // mapping name
                    .source(json);

            requestIndexer.add(rqst);

        } //process


    } //ElasticInserter

} //ReadFromKafka
```

I have installed ElesticSearch using `homebrew` and then started it using `elesticsearch` command  as shown below

[image]

however, when I start my program I got following error 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

my reputation below 50, can not comment.

I have a bit of suggestion:

- first check whether ES is up,
  see [Can't Connect to Elasticsearch (through Curl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110249/cant-connect-to-elasticsearch-through-curl).
- recommended to use the docker container to start ES, eg.  **docker run -d --name es -p 9200:9200 elasticsearch:2 -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0**
- BTW, You can try: modify `es.network.host` value to `0.0.0.0` in ES config `elasticsearch.yml`: